# Is it possible to create an app that will trigger an event when you send text message in a social media app like Instagram?

Tags: android, mobile, automation, mobile-application, social-media

I want to create an app that can record certain information whenever I text on social media like Instagram or messenger and save it in an excel or google sheet. I am new to mobile app development so i am wondering if this is even possible and how should i go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement totally depends on `Event/Broadcasts`(when the user sends the msg), and  **fortunately**, there is no way to get that kind of event.

After all, This is all about privacy. No app or Google devs will allow other apps to get these kinds of events.

Though-

1. u can get the current running app, but I think that is not your requirement.
2. You can read incoming msg through the `Notifications service`, but required notifications access permission.

Comment: Thanks, i get the concern. I have found that there are a lot of projects now which uses WhatsApp web API to automate or perform different tasks programmatically. If i only implement this for web version instead of the apps for the same. Will it be possible?